# Apache HttpClient GET with body

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to send an HTTP GET with a json object in its body. Is there a way to set the body of an [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) HttpGet? I am looking for the equivalent of HttpPost#setEntity.

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Nikita - My question is similar to the one you post, however I am asking specifically how to do so via the Apache HttpClient API. Thank you though.

Comment: The answer is oficially it's not possible. GET requests can't contain body according to specification. You need to use POST requests.

Comment: Please note that in the question you linked to it is indicated that a GET may have a body. The spec allows this. My question is simply whether this is possible via Apache's HttpClient.

Comment: Yes, you're right it's not prohibited by spec. But I'd say it's not possible.

Answer (score 46):

From what I know, you can't do this with the default HttpGet class that comes with the Apache library. However, you can subclass the *HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase* entity and set the method to GET. I haven't tested this, but I think the following example might be what you're looking for:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;

public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

Edit:

You could then do the following:

```
...
HttpGetWithEntity e = new HttpGetWithEntity();
...
e.setEntity(yourEntity);
...
response = httpclient.execute(e);
```

Comment: Seems to work, that's actually the only way I've found so far to send a body using a get request with any java library!

Comment: +1; @ScottSwank please accept the answer as it does indeed seem to work

Answer (score 12):

Using torbinsky's answer I created the above class. This lets me use the same methods for HttpPost.

```
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpPost {

    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    public HttpGetWithEntity(URI url) {
        super(url);
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code with a web service that I need to talk to on my project and no go. I just receive on the service daemon log "Internal application error, closing connection.". Jersey offered a HttpGet with entities (called differently), but sadly apache does not. This particular web service truly expects a GET request and not a POST.

Answer (score 4):

My approach is to use a `RequestBuilder`  (from `org.apache.http.client.methods` package).

It doesn't conform the same API as just using `HttpPost` but is much simpler than the one provided above.

```
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get(uri)
        .setEntity(new StringEntity(entity))
        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition torbinsky's answer, you can add these constructors to the class to make it easier to set the uri:

```
public HttpGetWithEntity(String uri) throws URISyntaxException{
    this.setURI(new URI(uri));
}

public HttpGetWithEntity(URI uri){
    this.setURI(uri);
}
```

The `setURI` method is inherited from `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase` and can also be used outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**How we can send request uri in this example just like HttpGet & HttpPost ???**

```
 public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
 {
    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";
    @Override
     public String getMethod() {
         return METHOD_NAME;
     } 

        HttpGetWithEntity e = new HttpGetWithEntity(); 
        e.setEntity(yourEntity); 
        response = httpclient.execute(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;

public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    public HttpGetWithEntity() {
        super();
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(final URI url) {
        super();
        setURI(url);
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(final String url) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(url));
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found @NotThreadSafe not found error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472392