# Create a HTTP GET request which sends JSON data in body with Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am having a problem when i integrate API of our partner. They always use Json data in body of HTTP request for both "POST" and "GET" method.

I'm using scalaj library for creating HTTP request but it can not send json data in Body for GET request. when i put json data to body, the Method will change to POST automatically.

I also tried to use default HttpUrlConnection in Java, but it have same problem. When i call setDoOutput method, HttpUrlConnection will change Method to POST.

How can I solve this problem in Scala?

Comment: Here is a solution using jetty-client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180431/http-get-request-with-body?rq=1

Comment: GET requests do NOT have a body...

Comment: @Thilo: Yes. I tried to use Jetty-client. It can create HTTP GET with body. Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 That is simply not true. There is nothing in the HTTP spec that says GET requests do not have a body

Comment: @thesteph let me rephrase, then, the server should ignore the body, if it exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body