# Send content body with HTTP GET Request in Java

Tags: java, http, get

I have a third party API which needs content body in a http GET request and doesn't accept any other forms of input.I cant make any changes to this API and the owners are not taking change requests to the API. I know that this is a bad design and all but is there any way this could be done ? I have tried apache httpurlconnection and java url apis, but haven't been able to achieve the same.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please provide more details, show what have you already tried.

Comment: Perhaps [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27319285/4385713) can be of any help.

Comment: @cascer1 perhaps not - it uses scala.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http get request with body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180431/http-get-request-with-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the below

```
public class HttpGetWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }
}

HttpGetWithBody getWithBody = new HttpGetWithBody ();
getWithBody.setEntity(y(new ByteArrayEntity(
            "<SOMEPAYLOAD FOR A GET ???>".toString().getBytes("UTF8"))););
getResponse = httpclient.execute(getWithBody );
```

Import needed will be `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;`