# Error in extending HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase

Tags: java, spring, http

I am trying to make a custom GET request that can take `body` with it for a 3rd part API. I wrote the following code for the same:

```
public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    public HttpGetWithEntity() {
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(URI uri) {
        this.setURI(uri);
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(String uri) {
        this.setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

The problem is `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase` class uses following annotation:

```
@NotThreadSafe
public abstract class HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase extends HttpRequestBase implements HttpEntityEnclosingRequest {
```

This extension has been removed from `org.apache.http.annotation`, so while compiling my application I receive the following error:

```
cannot access org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
class file for org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe not found
```

How can I avoid this as I am not able to find something from google searches and reading some other code that was extending `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`. Is there any other way to send body with a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

`@ThreadSafe` class not found compilation error occurs after updating your `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore` dependency version to `4.4.11` or above.
This `httpcore` version comes with:

```
Class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable removed
Class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe removed
Class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe removed
…
```

Instead of these removed classes `org.apache.http.annotation.Contract` annotation and `org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadingBehavior` `enum` were introduced.

So now you should refactor `@ThreadSafe` occurrences to `org.apache.http.annotation.Contract` annotation and pass T`hreadingBehavior` enum‘s value SAFE to specify thread-safe behavioral contract

```
@Contract(threading = ThreadingBehavior.SAFE)

@NotThreadSafe transforms to ThreadingBehavior.UNSAFE

@Immutable to ThreadingBehavior.IMMUTABLE or IMMUTABLE_CONDITIONAL
```

Comment: I can't change the annotation that is used in library class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going up the hierarchy and redefining classes that used `@NotThreadSafe` annotation.

First I made my own`HttpRequestBase`:

```
public abstract class MyHttpRequestBase extends AbstractExecutionAwareRequest implements HttpUriRequest, Configurable {
    private ProtocolVersion version;
    private URI uri;
    private RequestConfig config;

    public MyHttpRequestBase() {
    }

    public abstract String getMethod();

    public void setProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public ProtocolVersion getProtocolVersion() {
        return this.version != null ? this.version : HttpProtocolParams.getVersion(this.getParams());
    }

    public URI getURI() {
        return this.uri;
    }

    public RequestLine getRequestLine() {
        String method = this.getMethod();
        ProtocolVersion ver = this.getProtocolVersion();
        URI uriCopy = this.getURI();
        String uritext = null;
        if (uriCopy != null) {
            uritext = uriCopy.toASCIIString();
        }

        if (uritext == null || uritext.isEmpty()) {
            uritext = "/";
        }

        return new BasicRequestLine(method, uritext, ver);
    }

    public RequestConfig getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }

    public void setConfig(RequestConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void setURI(URI uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public void started() {
    }

    public void releaseConnection() {
        this.reset();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getMethod() + " " + this.getURI() + " " + this.getProtocolVersion();
    }
}
```

Then I made my own `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`:

```
public abstract class HttpEnclosingEntity extends MyHttpRequestBase implements HttpEntityEnclosingRequest {

    private HttpEntity entity;

    public HttpEnclosingEntity() {

    }

    public HttpEntity getEntity() {
        return this.entity;
    }

    public void setEntity(HttpEntity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public boolean expectContinue() {
        Header expect = this.getFirstHeader("Expect");
        return expect != null && "100-continue".equalsIgnoreCase(expect.getValue());
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        HttpEnclosingEntity clone = (HttpEnclosingEntity) super.clone();
        if (this.entity != null) {
            clone.entity = (HttpEntity)CloneUtils.cloneObject(this.entity);
        }

        return clone;
    }
}
```

Then I used this class to make my own `HttpGetWithEntity`:

```
public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEnclosingEntity {
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    public HttpGetWithEntity() {

    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(URI uri) {
        this.setURI(uri);
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(String uri) {
        this.setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }
}
```

It was like re-inventing the wheel, resulting in code-repetition, but I was left with no other choice due to the mismatch in my current version of apache library and the version used by these files. This mismatch lead to the error related to `@NotThreadSafe`.